What type of plug is this? Supplies power to dash cam
What type of plug is this?  Supplies power to dash cam.  It’s not a micro USB see photo.

Please post the dimensions of the plug and an in-focus picture if possible.

The shape looks like Micro-HDMI, but it doesn't seem to have enough pins.

Calling @DavideAndrea!

Looks like the two connectors could be a Mini-A connector and a Micro-B connector.  There are examples in the connector section of the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Mini_connectors
As mentioned in comments, a photograph with the connectors in focus and something next to the connectors that shows scale is essential to get answers that are better than guesses.
